# checking for user ip in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table for user

```
id_agent   name   agent_center  agent_name  agent_password
 1         black   ABCE          black       1234
 2         white   XYZ           white       1234
```

i have another table for storing ip

```
id_center   center_name    ipdetails
 1          ABCE           118.102.244.52,127.0.0.1  //black ip 118.102.244.52
 2          XYZ            192.168.0.1,123.87.65.43
 3          LKA
```

now if i try to login with `agent_name=black` and `agent_password=1234` it will check the 2nd table if the ip is present in `center_name` related with the user.in this case `center_name=ABCE`.so if the ip of that user is present in ABCE it will advance or else rejects.how can i do this check from a function.

i have already a function that checks ip from a single row in a table

```
function check_ip_detailss($center_id,$center_name){
$sql_IP=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM center_listt WHERE center_name='$center_name' AND ipdetails LIKE '%$center_id%'");
$nos=mysql_num_rows($sql_IP);
if($nos){
    $ip_mess="";
} else {
    $ip_mess="<h1 align=\"center\" style=\"font-size:24px\">Your IP(".$center_id.") is currently inactive. 
    <br/><br/>Please contact your system administrator for inquiries.</h1>";
}

return $ip_mess;
}
?>
```

and then calling the function in index.php file like

```
$center_ip_status=check_ip_details($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],"Cegura FT");
if($center_ip_status!=''){
echo $center_ip_status;exit;
}
if($_SESSION["login_id"]){
header("location:home.php");exit;
}
//if found it open the login form here.
```

the table from where it is checking

```
id_center   agent_center  ip
 1           LKM          122.23.32.54,123.56.87.82,321,45,65,34,881.43.23.45
```

how can i do a function which will check the user `agent_center` and then look for the ip of that user in the 2nd table

Comment: ehe.the question is how can i do this checking

Comment: I suggest you making a new table to store the IP's separately and assigned to the center it belongs to in `INT` format so you can easily compare one IP against another with `INET_ATON`/`INET_NTOA`.

Comment: The way you're storing IP addresses here is sub-optimal. You need a one-to-many relationship but you're using some kind of commma-separated value that MySQL can't possibly hope to understand.

Comment: the question is what have you already done, and where did you get stuck. what is the error message, etc

Comment: regardless to the way you want to approach, don't store comma separated values in columns, normalize your RDB

Comment: the comma separated value storing for ip is already running .i will surely take a note from the next time.thanks

Comment: Then provide the portion of code you're working to make the verification that you have so far and what exactly is the portion of it not working or that you are having trouble it. Given what you said that its already "running".

Comment: Not a useful thing to do checking IP addresses in this day and age. DHCP etc. makes them quite useless as a security mechanism

Answer (score 1):

Do a join of the 2 tables based on centre name, with a where clause to check the name and password, and also use FIND_IN_SET to check the ip address.

Example code. To just know if they can log in you just need to check if this query returns a row.

```
SELECT *
FROM users a
INNER JOIN centers b
ON a.agent_center = b.center_name
WHERE a.agent_name = 'black' 
AND a.agent_password = '1234'
AND FIND_IN_SET('118.102.244.52', b.ipdetails) > 0
```

But this is not going to be efficient compared to a normalised database design

EDIT - php function to check the details when passed the user name, password and ip address:-

```
<?php

function check_ip_details_for_user($agent_name, $agent_password, $center_id)
{
    $ip_mess="";
    $sql = "SELECT a.agent_center
            FROM users a
            INNER JOIN centers b
            ON a.agent_center = b.center_name
            WHERE a.agent_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($agent_name)."' 
            AND a.agent_password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($agent_name)."'
            AND FIND_IN_SET('".mysql_real_escape_string($center_id)."', b.ipdetails) > 0";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);     
    $nos = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if(!$nos)
    {
        $ip_mess="<h1 align=\"center\" style=\"font-size:24px\">Username or password not correct for this ip address. 
        <br /><br />Please contact your system administrator for inquiries.</h1>";
    }

    return $ip_mess;
}
?>
```

Comment: yes its returning rows.how can i make it dynamic that will check for any user

Comment: Modified with some suggested php to check the details.

Comment: thank you dude for the update.so suppose i have a agentname black and pass 1234 with agent_center=abc in one table and center_name=abc containing user black ip in other table thn i should be able to access.but its goin on to the error msg of ur function.or mayb i am calling the function the wrong way.

Comment: I have checked on SQL fiddle and the SQL should work ( http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2056b/1 ). Possible you have some extra spaces in the ipdetails field